# What would cause Apache to display a bomb icon for a specific directory?

Tags: apache-2.2

A user of mine came to me with a question today that has me stumped: **Why do `.musecore` files on our web server show a bomb icon ([image: Apache Bomb Icon]) instead of a folder icon?**

More generally, how does Apache decide what icon to display, and where can I inspect and/or change that configuration?

Comment: See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#addicon (+1 for the title)

Comment: And obviously, "this page" is fixed now. Yay serverfault! I've adjusted the link to go to archive.org.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By [default](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf.in), the bomb icon is displayed for core dumps, and the default configuration assumes that any filename **or directory name** matching a regex like `^*core$` must be a core dump.

This option is controlled by the [`AddIcon` directive of mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#addicon) which is also visible in the [default `extra/httpd-autoindex.conf` file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf.in):

```
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core
```

Comment: Source: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf.in

Comment: I made a file applecore as a test, and put some text in it, and it showed up as a bomb.

Comment: That's indeed a strange default! Thank for the hint!

Answer (score -1):

If for some reason you have named your directory 'core' the bomb image will be displayed. If it not a core dump, simply change the directory name to something else and the bomb image will be replaced with the usual folder image.

Comment: This isn't really a new/unique answer from the one that was already posted and accepted nearly a year ago... Consider posting comments like this as actual comments (once you have enough rep that you're allowed to).
Just FYI